# How to know the handle of the client that disconnects form a q service triggering the .z.pc function, kdb+

Tags: kdb

I have to log disconnects and I am defining a `.z.pc` function to do this. However, I'm unsure how to best to get the handle of the process that has disconnected. I do record the handle and host, when it connects, using the `.z.po` function. Any insight would be appreciated.

My function looks like this:

```
.z.pc:{handles,:(.z.t;.z.h;.z.w;"d")}
```

The issue is the function is triggered after disconnect so `.z.w` has to be an historic value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit "x" variable inside `.z.pc` is the handle of the disconnected process

Comment: Thank-you very much!